# How do I adjust overexposure in certain parts of the image only, using darktable?

Tags: exposure, darktable, highlights, retouching

I am very new to RAW editing. I clicked few pic and they have overexposure problem in selected area using `darktable`. I can't find out a way to edit/remove the overexposed part only. I have tried `highlight reconstruction` but that did not work.

Is there anyway to darken some selected portion?

I am using darktable 2.2.3

This is a picture I have taken... so I want his bald spot to look bit nicer, as an example.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B02WblgE6NEvQlgwQnBYaHp4RkE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the ["highlight reconstruction" module](http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch03s04.html.php#highlight_reconstruction) doesn't actually adjust the exposure of hilight areas itself, it only determines how to handle areas that are clipped in the RAW file when they're pulled down to a level that doesn't result in clipping in the output. You can use the very useful RAW overexposure and output overexposure warnings [available in the bottom panel of darkroom mode](http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch03s03s09.html.php#rawoverexposed) to check both conditions.

For doing the actual selective exposure adjustment, you can use the ["shadows and highlights" module](http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch03s04.html.php#shadows_and_highlights) to do this based on the existing values, possibly combining with a [drawn mask](http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch03s02s07.html.php) for greater selection control. For complete manual control of the process, you could use a drawn mask with the basic ["exposure" module](http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch03s04.html.php#exposure), which resembles traditional dodging/burning. If the overexposure is primarily in the sky or otherwise varies across the image, you might find the ["graduated density" module](http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch03s04s05.html.php#graduated_density) useful. Sometimes a combination of these methods can work well.

UPDATE: That's the general answer; after looking at the image that you added to the question, I see that a light source next to a shiny object has completely blown out a large area. Since there isn't much information there to work with, you'll probably need to use the ["color reconstruction" module](http://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch03s04.html.php#color_reconstruction), which can actually synthesize color information based on the area surrounding the blown highlights. Try starting with these values:

- threshold: 100
- spatial extent: 160
- range extent: 5

and adjust from there.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your image and its very blown out in those highlights. Darktable alone didn't do a great job in an acceptable amount of time for me using my goto lowpass, color reconstruction, and selective denoising with hand-drawn masks. From there, I brought it into Krita and it was quick work to use the smart patch tool followed by a blending brush.

My results here:

[image]